# How do I enable Directory Browsing for an virtual web directory using wix?

Tags: iis-7, installation, wix

I want to enable "Directory Browsing" for the for the following virtual web directory using WIX.

```
<iis:WebVirtualDir Id="LogsVirDir" Alias="Logs"  Directory="ESGLOGFILES" />
```

How do I accomplish this using WIX?
[image: IIS Directory Browsing Option]

[image: Directory Browsing Enabled]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my research Wix currently does not have any capability to enable `Directory Browsing` using the standard set of actions. The one way I have found to do this is using a combination of Wix Custom Actions and IIS's [`Appcmd.exe`](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/114/getting-started-with-appcmdexe). Note this command will create a `web.config` file if one does not exist.

```
<CustomAction Id="EnableDirectoryBrowsing"
              Execute="deferred"
              ExeCommand='[WindowsFolder]system32\inetsrv\APPCMD.EXE set config "ESG Website/logs" /section:directoryBrowse /enabled:true'
              Directory="TARGETDIR"
              Return="check"
              Impersonate="no"/>


<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="EnableDirectoryBrowsing" Before="InstallFinalize">Not Installed</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Answer (score 4):

Wouldn't a simpler solution be to use the web.config system.webserver property like :

```
<directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
```

Comment: Sometimes, yes.  The three techniques in preferred order are: 1) developer maintained web.config 2) wix iis extension 3) web.config xpath update 4) appcmd custom action.  In older versions of IIS #1 and #3 weren''t available. If an application has fixed variation points, mutually exclusive web.config components can be used (web.config-qa, web.config-prod)    If the variation point is variable then option 2 or 3 can be used at installtime with properties.  #4 is a last resort because it's out of process and non-transactional.

Comment: FYI- the directoryBrowse element was introduced in IIS 7.0 so this solution would not work with IIS 6.0 if that is a concern for a given project.

Answer (score 0):

Im using wix v3.8

try adding ConfigurableDirectory in your Feature

ex: `<Feature Id='TestName' Title='Test Web' ConfigurableDirectory='INSTALLDIR' Level='1'>`

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following code

```
<Control Id="Browse" Type="PushButton" X="304" Y="210" Width="56" Height="17" Text="!(loc.CustomizeDlgBrowse)">
          <Publish Event="SelectionBrowse" Value="BrowseDlg">1</Publish>
</Control>
```

Take the value of this in the variable you want and use it.

Comment: Just to clarify, your answer will allow me enable Directory Browsing for a virtual directory on IIS?

Comment: you mean you have a virtual directory say yahoo and you want to map it to some directory?

Comment: Yes, I am referring to virtual directories in IIS. I am already able to create them using WIX, I want to enable `Directory Browsing` for these virtual directories.

Comment: doesn't answer the question